# Primefaces custom theme - selectone menu trigger

Tags: css, jquery-ui, primefaces

I'm trying to create custom theme css for Primefaces 6.1, on the select one menu trigger I'm trying to change the bajcground color of the trigger when it's hovered and focused. Here's what I've tried

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger:hover
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Now this works for hover but obviously changes as soon as the cursor is no longer hovering over it. Now I'm aware of the `.ui-state-hover`, `.ui-state-focused` etc. However doing the following has no effect

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger .ui-state-hover,
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger .ui-state-focused
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read/learn about css specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the approach, we need to specify the container, the state and then the specific component class so the correct way is

```
.ui-widget-container .ui-state-hover .ui-selectonemenutrigger,
.ui-widget-container .ui-state-focus .ui-selectonemenutrigger
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```